# Assigning value from batch file to Jlabel

Tags: java, batch-file, jframe

I have a jTextfield where you enter in half of the computer name and when you click search, it searches the active directory and finds the full computer name. That part works fine. My issue is assigning the computer name to a JLabel in my Java GUI. The JLabel I'm referring to that needs the computer name assigned to it is selectedComputerFromAD. Currently when I hit search the label just stays blank, but I know the query is working because I can see the full computer name in command prompt.
Any suggestions?

```
JButton searchComputerButton = new JButton("Search");
        searchComputerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String line;
                BufferedWriter bw = null;
                BufferedWriter writer =null;
                try {
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                //String lineToRemove = "OU=Workstations";

                String s = null;

                Process p = null;
                try {
                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c:\\computerQuery.bat computerName");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {

                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\computerQuery.bat");

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }
                StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer(); // new trial
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
                        .getInputStream()));

                try {

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        System.out.println(line);

                        //textArea.append(line);

                        String dn = "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
                        LdapName ldapName = new LdapName(dn);
                        String commonName = (String) ldapName.getRdn(ldapName.size() - 1).getValue();
                        System.out.println(commonName);
                        System.out.println(commonName);

                        textArea.append(String.format("  %s%n", commonName));
                        textArea.append(commonName);
                        JLabel selectedComputerFromAD = new JLabel();
                        selectedComputerFromAD.setText(commonName);
                        selectedComputerFromAD.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        selectedComputerFromAD.setForeground(Color.RED);
                        selectedComputerFromAD.setBounds(349, 84, 102, 19);
                        frame.getContentPane().add(selectedComputerFromAD);
                    }
                    ComputerQuery.sendParam();

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                } catch (InvalidNameException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } finally

                {
                    try {
                        fw.close();

                    }

                    catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {

                    in.close();

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }


                ComputerQuery.sendParam();

            }
        });
```

The method you see at the end of this code "ComputerQuery.sendParam();" is here

```
 public static void sendParam(){
      try{
          String val = MISControlPanel.textField.getText(); //Put whatever you want to pass as a prefix in place of "Computer"
            jLabel1.setText(val);
            Process p ;
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c:\\computerQuery.bat "+val+"");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

Comment: should your program  print just one computer name?then why do you create jlable everytime.if not you should set a layout appropriate to frame before add jlables

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest and most lowlevel solutions would be to redirect the output of the batch:

```
computerquery.bat FooUser > resultofbatch.txt
```

Depending on what is inside the batch you can add the redirection there too

*computerquery.bat*

```
@echo off
...
myfanceexedoingmagic.exe %1 > resultofbatch.txt
```

In either case simply read the created file. You should delete it before you run the batch a second time.

A more difficult solution would be to parse the output of the executed command directly, but I don't think this is worth the effort.